# Using To Sphere with Mirror modifier enabled

Tags: edit-mode, mirror-modifier

I'm editing a mesh with a Mirror modifier on the X axis. I want to apply [To Sphere](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/transform/to_sphere.html) (Alt-Shift-S) to points that lie on the mirror boundary. I expect the whole shape (the part I'm editing and the mirrored part) to end up more spherical.

Here's a picture. In the foreground is the result you get if you apply it to half of the sphere. You can see that the boundary points turned into a circle but actually pinched in a bit. In the background, I just applied the mirror modifier and then used To Sphere.

Is there some way to get the more sphere-like result without applying the mirror first? (Keeping in mind the actual mesh is much more complicated: I'm not trying to just make a sphere-ized cube).

[image: comparing To Sphere with/without mirror modifier applied.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the 3D cursor at the center of your object and select *3D Cursor* in the *Transform Pivot Point* panel:

[image]